# Nginx not serving multiple locations

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx configuration file to serve gitbucket and jenkins from the same machine.
I can reach bitbucket but when i type domain/jenkins/ i end up on gitbuckets 404 page.
Whats wrong with my configuration?

```
server {
listen 80;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

listen 443;

ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

ssl on;
ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location /jenkins/ {
  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8081;
  }

  location / {
  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_connect_timeout   150;
  proxy_send_timeout      100;
  proxy_read_timeout      100;
  proxy_buffers           4 32k;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass. Looks like you have to do something like this:

location ~ ^/jenkins(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8081;
}

location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
...as you have it...
}

Comment: Tried it and does not work, sorry. Same result i end up on the 404 page of gitbucket.